# Getting GET response from Postman but not from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I have a MongoDB that I can pull data from inside of Postman like this: `http://localhost:8080/employees`. This works just fine, but if I make the same request from my react front end, then nothing happens.

This is my `index.js` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my `App.js` file:

```
import './App.css';

import ListEmployeeComponent from './components/ListEmployeeComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ListEmployeeComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the component that I need to show the data from the MongoDB on:

```
class ListEmployeeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            employees: []
        }
    }

    compondentDidMount(){
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res)=> {
            this.setState({employees: res.data})
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {console.log(this.props)}
                <h2 className="text-center">Employee List</h2>
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Employee First Name</th>
                                <th>Employee Last Name</th>
                                <th>Employee Email Id</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.employees.map(
                                    employee =>
                                    <tr key = {employee.id}>
                                        <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                                        <td>{employee.emailId}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}


export default ListEmployeeComponent;
```

The Javascript console only has this one message as far as I can tell:
`[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...`
So what's the deal? Why am I not getting a response from React but I do in Postman and in my URL.

And finally, this is where I am using `axios`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const EMPLOYEES_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/employees";

class EmployeeService {
    getEmployees(){
        console.log("hello");
        return axios.get(EMPLOYEES_API_BASE_URL);
    }
}

// Not exporting the class, but an object of this class so that we can use the object to call these methods ^
export default new EmployeeService();
```

As you can see, there is no employee data on my page:
[image]

EDIT: This is my Network tab:
[image: Network tab]

This is the controller in the backend:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    // Auto-inject EmployeeRepository Class into this class so we can use the object
    // without calling 'new EmployeeRepository'
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

    // GET all employees
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepo.findAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you see the request in the network tab? Is CORS set up on the server correctly? We will be needing more information in order to help you with this problem.

Comment: Okay, I added a screen shot from the network tab. Does that look correct?

Comment: I also have @CrossOrigin in my controller. I will add that to my question.

Comment: I don't see the request in the network panel. Are you sure that the `getEmployees` method is being called?

Comment: I thought I was. I am attempting to call it in ComponentDidMount in my `ListEmployeeComponent` component, but you make a valid point... because I have `console.log("hello");` in that function and I am not seeing it in the console. What would cause this to not run? You can see where I am calling it above^. The request is this part `    compondentDidMount(){
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res)=> {
            this.setState({employees: res.data})
        });
    }`

Comment: Also, what would the request look like in the Network tab?

Comment: It should be `componentDidMount` not `compondentDidMount`.

Comment: Try to return Employees Data form getEmployees() instead of axios promise

Comment: AHHHHHH yes stupid typo. That fixed my issue. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the api is not being called, so the problem rests in your api call flow. You could track where the problem is by putting debug prints (it is better to use more meaningful logs than `hello`) in every step of your app's flow.

If you do this you would notice something is wrong with the `componentDidMount()` function as it is not being called. It is a simple typo.